# passing td value to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass the the td value to java script,from java script i post that value  to the php page where it contains query.can any one guide me how  to pass the td value  to java script,i tried but i don't know how to pass this value .thanks

Below is my js code :

```
<script>

function myFunction() {

 // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var mcc = document.getElementById("mcc").value;
var mnc = document.getElementById("mnc").value;
var url = "testpage2/config.php";
var vars = "mcc="+mcc+"&mnc="+mnc;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.send(vars); 

        }
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<?php    
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplierprice ");   
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{    
if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }           
echo '  <td class="edit region '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>
        <td class="edit country '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td class="edit networkname '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td id="mcc" class="edit mcc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>   
        <td id="mnc" class="edit mnc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
        <td class="edit mnp '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>';           
    $ColumnNames = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'supplierprice' AND column_name NOT
IN ('supp_price_id','region', 'country', 'networkname', 'mcc', 'mnc', 'mnp'
)") or die("mysql error"); 
$columnArray=array();
$i=0;
while($rows1=mysql_fetch_array($ColumnNames))
{           
    $columnArray[]=$rows1[0];    
echo '<td  width="0px;" class="edit '.$columnArray[$i].' '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows[$columnArray[$i]].'</td>';   
        echo '<td><input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="" /></td>';        
                           $i++;
}
            echo '</tr>';
    }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` is for `input` elements. For others(like `td`, `th`, `div`, `span`...) use `innerHTML`:

```
var mcc = document.getElementById("mcc").innerHTML;
var mnc = document.getElementById("mnc").innerHTML;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,i tried but its not posting the mcc ans mnc to the config.php can you guide me pls and can you check the java script i think something wrong there

Comment: First of all check your dev tools(f12) network tab and check if the desired content was sent and the http code was *200*(request complete). If checks, try a `print_r($_POST);` on your php file and see if those vars has arrived.

Comment: thanks i checked the content not sent its shows 'Array
(
)' can you guide me how to pass it i am new to javascript its very helpfull for me

Comment: Look at [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/). Reload you page, open dev tools(f12), open network tab and then start your ajax action. On that tab will appear a new item like is shown on the second image on the post. On the tab *headers* will appear your parameters, check if they're right. On tab *response* will appear the response(the `print_r`) content. If there was shown empty, then the parameters are no sent.